# os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath("adb.exe")) Return false

Tags: python, windows, python-3.6

Why does `os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath("adb.exe"))` return false?
i have adb.exe in script dir same with `os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath("fastboot.exe"))`
but when i copy them to my python dir, and then start interactive shell, eg. `os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath("adb.exe"))` gives me True.
Or there is better way to validate if file exist in script dir.

Comment: Because python is actually running from python's dir, not the script location

Comment: You can get the script's directory using `directory, filepath = os.path.split(__file__)`

Comment: but, the problem is that these files could be in other directories. like, in my pc is c:\adb.exe and on onther pc this could be c:\scripts\python\adb.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath("adb.exe"))` returns `False` is because when you run the script, python is actually running from its installation directory, *not* the script location.

If you want to get the current folder path you can use:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

or as @blakev suggested:

```
os.path.split(__file__)[0]
```

Thus you can check a file exists in the scripts location using:

```
os.path.isfile(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + os.sep + filename)
```

---

Note:

`os.sep` contains the appropriate separator used by your operating systems file system, so `\` on Windows systems.

`__file__` exists only when running a script file, it won't work just running python in the command line. It returns the full path and name of the script. As an example, running a script on my desktop called *script.py* it may return `C:\Users\Nick A\Desktop\script.py`

Comment: Im newbie, so please, tell me what does _ _file_ _ mean

Comment: @Szymon `__file__` is the location of the script that's running, including the file name, for example on your desktop it may evaluate to `C:\Users\Szymon R\Desktop\script.py` on a Windows system

Comment: To clarify, python.exe could be run with any working directory. It's either explicitly set by or implicitly inherited from the parent process. Assuming python.exe or py.exe is associated with Python scripts, then when you double click on a .py script, normally Explorer runs Python with the working directory set to the script directory, but no script should depend on that.